# What is the average wait time in this trivial example?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose we are at a noodle place, there are n seats and each patrons eat noodle within a time of S seconds.

Suppose that all the n patrons start to eat at the same time, and finish at the same time. What is the average wait time in this case?

I'm guessing that the average wait time is the maximum wait time which is S seconds. But should it be S/n seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think S/n would be correct because you're looking for the average, not the wait time of one person (S).

Or it could be wait time S * number of people, and the average of that. $\frac{S*n}{n}$